# What is wrong with my if-else statements?

Tags: python, if-statement

I wrote code to find the average of the given data. I am not getting the desired output, I do not know what is wrong.

Here is the code:

```
student_1 = raw_input().split()
student_2 = raw_input().split()
student_3 = raw_input().split()
rec_1 = {'name' : student_1[0], 'math' : int(student_1[1]), 'physics' :    int(student_1[2]), 'chemistry' : int(student_1[3])}
rec_2 = {'name' : student_2[0], 'math' : int(student_2[1]), 'physics' : int(student_2[2]), 'chemistry' : int(student_2[3])}
rec_3 = {'name' : student_3[0], 'math' : int(student_3[1]), 'physics' : int(student_3[2]), 'chemistry' : int(student_3[3])}

name_of_student = raw_input()

if name_of_student == rec_1['name'] is True:
    s1 = (rec_1['math']+rec_1['physics']+rec_1['chemistry'])
    n1 = len(student_1) - 1
    print s1 / n1

elif name_of_student == rec_2['name'] is True:
    s2 = (rec_2['math']+rec_2['physics']+rec_2['chemistry'])
    n2 = len(student_2) - 1
    print s2 / n2

elif name_of_student == rec_3['name'] is True:
    s3 = (rec_3['math']+rec_3['physics']+rec_3['chemistry'])
    n3 = len(student_3) - 1
    print s3 / n3

else:
    print "Record not available"
```

Input:

3

K 67 68 69

A 70 98 63

M 52 56 60

M

Desired output:
56.00

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: Remove the `is True` in your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are putting too much into them. Remove the `is True` part:

```
if name_of_student == rec_1['name']:
```

With `is True`, you're checking this:

```
if name_of_student == (rec_1['name'] is True):
```

Since `rec_1['name']` will never be a boolean value, the parenthesized part will be `False`, and since `name_of_student` will never be `False`, the whole thing will evaluate to `False`, failing to find the student's name.

What you probably thought you were doing is closer to this:

```
if (name_of_student == rec_1['name']) is True:
```

This will probably produce the expected result, as the parenthesized comparison will produce a boolean value which, in CPython (the standard Python implementation), should have the same identity as other instances of itself due to integer interning. However, you should not rely on that. Just remove the `is True` part and you'll get the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Makes sense, and it works now! Thank you!